# When replying to email in Outlook 2010, how do I get it to automatically select the account I want it to send to? I have multiple accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

I have multiple accounts and want to get outlook 2010 to automatically select the account it uses to send my reply emails - based on whatever email address is indicated in the "TO:" field for that received email.

The account outlook usually selects is whatever account the email was received in.  But the problem is that all my secondary email accounts are already being routed to my primary account, and my primary account is where I am replying from.

If someone can come up with some VB code or directions on how to do this, I will love you forever.

Comment: `Issue 1` This may be more difficult than you think. Suppose I am Edward Bear, known to my friends as Teddy or Ted with an email address of E.Bear@Isp.Com. The value in the To field of the emails you send me is not "E.Bear@Isp.Com" but the name you use for me ("Bear, Edward", "Ted Bear", etc.). Can you deduce the account name from the names that people use for you?  `Issue 2` Can you deduce your account name from the Sender? For example, do I always use your account 1 while John always uses your account 2? `Issue 3` Would you know what to do with a Outlook macro if it was supplied?

Comment: Can you read either of the following questions?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558368/how-to-import-the-outlook-mail-data-to-excel) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697493/update-excel-sheet-based-on-outlook-mail) In both cases the questioner could not explain what they wanted clearly so the questions were closed as too vague. Before that happened, I posted tutorials about Outlook macros. What I do not know is in those tutorials are visible to anyone else.